# jboss session temp directory

Tags: java, ejb, jboss5.x

I have a EJB bean that needs to create files. Are there some kind of temp directory for single user, so it will not interfere with other user's files and files will be deleted once user disconnects?

Comment: Can't you just generate unique file names?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I could generate unique names, but what about automatic cleanup?

Comment: Cleanup? No problem! Add [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to your proyect.